# problem in connecting zabbix to remote DB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, zabbix

I installed zabbix 4.0 in centOs 7 and configured it to connect to remote mysql.
But log file says that it can not connect to DB.

I tried to telnet to DB machine and I was OK!

```
telnet 10.1.13.33 3306
Trying 10.1.13.33...
Connected to 10.1.13.33.
```

here is my /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf:

```
SourceIP=10.1.9.140
LogFile=/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server.log
LogFileSize=0
DebugLevel=5
PidFile=/var/run/zabbix/zabbix_server.pid
SocketDir=/var/run/zabbix
DBHost=10.1.13.33
DBName=zabbix
DBUser=zabbix
DBPassword=******************
DBPort=3306
SNMPTrapperFile=/var/log/snmptrap/snmptrap.log
Timeout=4
AlertScriptsPath=/usr/lib/zabbix/alertscripts
ExternalScripts=/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts
LogSlowQueries=3000
```

When starting zabbix, in /var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server.log there is a line like this:

```
[Z3001] connection to database 'zabbix' failed: [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.1.13.33' (13)
database is down: reconnecting in 10 seconds
```

Comment: Does the zabbix database already exists?

Comment: Yes, the database already exists and tables was created.

Comment: definitely looks like a database error, check zabbix grants on MySQL: `SHOW GRANTS FOR zabbix`

Comment: All accesses to the user have been given

Answer (score 0):

By default, Zabbix server does not understand which IP to be listened. So you have to also mention your `ListenIP` in `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf`:

```
ListenIP=<your_ip>
```